# How to select all fields including id and name value in select box using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

I have the select box.

```
<select ng-model="sub_class_name" class="form-control"> 
<option ng-repeat="x in myData" value="{{x}}">{{x.sub_class_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Am passing value to a controller like this :

```
$scope.alertdata = function() {
var parameter = {
            "first_name": $scope.first_name,
            "middle_name": $scope.middle_name, 
            "subclass": [$scope.sub_class_name]
        }
}
```

After printing the parameter

```
alert(JSON.stringify(parameter));
```

Am getting stringified JSON output i.e.,

```
{"first_name":"Prashanth","middle_name":"H","last_name":"Rotti",
"subclass":["{\"sub_class_id\":3,\"sub_class_name\":\"Dependent \"}"]}
```

I dont want slashes `["{\"sub_class_id\":3,\"sub_class_name\":\"Dependent \"}"]`

```
I want JSON output like this.
{"first_name":"Prashanth","middle_name":"H","last_name":"Rotti",
"subclass":[{"sub_class_id":"3","sub_class_name":"Dependent"}] }
```

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse

"subclass": [JSON.parse($scope.sub_class_name)]

Comment: Use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead in order to select the whole object. Now you are selecting the value of one option which is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as answer, as it is not possible to format data properly in comment:
**Update **
Since datatype expected is string in JSON format, so you can initialize like this

```
$scope.sub_class_name = "{}" // Or $scope.sub_class_name ="[]"; based on data type it may be
$scope.alertdata = function() {
var parameter = {
            "first_name": $scope.first_name,
            "middle_name": $scope.middle_name, 
            "subclass": [JSON.parse($scope.sub_class_name)]
        }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(parameter));
```

Let me know if you face any issue with this.

Comment: Hi, I have multiple select fields and I have to parse them but am getting an error.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: If I select all the select option then it is working else it throws an exception..

Comment: this means.. the value of $scope.sub_class_name is not JSON type always. Can you please show the value of $scope.sub_class when it throws error.

Comment: IF you are getting error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0, that means the vallue of $scope.sub_class is undefined in that case (u for undefined)

before passing the variable to JSON.parse, you should check that it should not be undefined. 

You can initialize $scope.sub_class_name to an object ot array.

Comment: Wait..something wrong.. I am fixing my answer above

Comment: Yup worked. :). We need to assign null before inserting. Ok code works fine is there other way that we can assign null I mean in input field default value="NULL" like that.

Comment: null itself is a vallue.. So I am not sure how you can set this as default

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse()`

It will do the trick.

[image]

Comment: JSON.parse parameter I have to use $scope.sub_class_name.?

Comment: @PrashanthHarish yes, exactly :)